# ClearCase label parent folders of a file

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

With a given file path, how to label all parent folders until the VOB level?

for example, file path: \VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1\file1.xml

The following elements I want to be labelled with LABEL1:

```
\VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1\file1.xml
\VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1
\VOB1\dir1\subdir1
\VOB1\dir1
```

With mklabel command, easy to do:

```
cleartool mklabel LABEL1 \VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1\file1.xml \VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1 \VOB1\dir1\subdir1 \VOB1\dir1
```

However, I want the paths to be calculated intelligently.

The parameter of mklabel -rec don't suit this purpose because the top parent folder may containt lots of other files/dirs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "filePath=\VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1\file1.xml"
set "wantedParent=VOB1"

set "thisPath="
set "labelPaths="
set "labelThisPath="
if "%filePath:~0,1%" equ "\" set "filePath=%filePath:~1%"
for %%a in ("%filePath:\=" "%") do (
   set "thisPath=!thisPath!\%%~a"
   if defined labelThisPath (
      set "labelPaths=!thisPath! !labelPaths!"
   ) else if "%%~a" equ "%wantedParent%" (
      set "labelThisPath=true"
   )
)

ECHO cleartool mklabel %labelPaths%
```

Output:

```
cleartool mklabel \VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1\file1.xml \VOB1\dir1\subdir1\moredir1 \VOB1\dir1\subdir1 \VOB1\dir1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no native way to get the list of parent folders (unless [`cleartool lsfolder -ancestor`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsfolder.htm) works), you would simply 'cd ..' until mklabel fails (which would mean you are outside of the vob)

```
cleartool mklabel LABEL1 . || exit
cd ..
```

In bash:

```
while true; do cleartool mklabel LABEL1 . || exit; cd ..; done
```